Matrix4x4 from translation rotation scale
How do I create a System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 from a translation, rotation and scale?
I have 2 methods that I am toying around with:
public static class Matrix4x4Extensions
{
    // Uses multiplication of other matrices to create the final matrix. Wasteful.
    public static Matrix4x4 CreateTransformation(Vector3 position, Quaternion quaternion, Vector3 scales)
    {
        var translationMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(position);
        var rotationMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(quaternion);
        var scaleMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreateScale(scales);

        // Combine the matrices: scale -> rotate -> translate
        return scaleMatrix * rotationMatrix * translationMatrix;
    }

    // Uses an implementation from Unity to create a matrix4x4 directly.
    public static Matrix4x4 CreateTransformationUnity(Vector3 position, Quaternion quaternion, Vector3 scales)
    {
        const uint p = 0x00000000;
        const uint n = 0x80000000;

        var v = new Vector4(quaternion.X, quaternion.Y, quaternion.Z, quaternion.W);
        var v2 = v + v;

        var yxw = new Vector3((uint)v.Y ^ n, (uint)v.X ^ p, (uint)v.W ^ n);
        var zwx = new Vector3((uint)v.Z ^ p, (uint)v.W ^ n, (uint)v.X ^ n);
        var wzy = new Vector3((uint)v.W ^ n, (uint)v.Z ^ n, (uint)v.Y ^ p);

        var c0 = v2.Y * yxw - v2.Z * zwx + Vector3.UnitX;
        var c1 = v2.Z * wzy - v2.X * yxw + Vector3.UnitY;
        var c2 = v2.X * zwx - v2.Y * wzy + Vector3.UnitZ;

        return new Matrix4x4(
            c0.X * scales.X, c0.Y * scales.X, c0.Z * scales.X, 0.0f,
            c1.X * scales.Y, c1.Y * scales.Y, c1.Z * scales.Y, 0.0f,
            c2.X * scales.Z, c2.Y * scales.Z, c2.Z * scales.Z, 0.0f,
            position.X, position.Y, position.Z, 1.0f
        );
    }
}

Originally I created the second method to improve my performance a little but what surprises me is that they don't return the same result. So I am confused: which implementation is correct?
I have tried figuring this out on my own but with how complicated matrix math is (and with how woefully unqualified I am to tackle it) I am looking for a little confirmation.
UPDATE
Turns out Unity's implementation was wrong from the beginning.
What are they even doing over there?
